# Trying to create a program that can Identify numbers, characters, a string, and special symbols such as @ and $

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;    
public class LetterOrDigit {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    
            System.out.print("Enter a character: ");    
            char ch = input.next().charAt(0);    
            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {    
                System.out.print(ch + " is an lower-case letter");    
            }if((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')) {    
                System.out.print(ch + " is an upper-case letter");    
            }else if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {    
                System.out.print(ch + " is a digit");    
            } else {    
                System.out.print(ch + " is neither a letter nor a digit");    
    }    
}
```

This is what I have, I can identify the Capitals and lower case as well as numbers, but I need help if it has abc I need it to come out as "Invalid" and if it a symbol such as @ or $ I need it to be " is neither a letter or digit".

Comment: You've missed `else` in front of the second `if` which tests for 'A'..'Z'

Comment: 'char ch = input.next().charAt(0);' takes the first character, and disregards the rest. So, that won't distinguish between user entering _a_ vs. _abc_.  Try `String entry = input.next();  if (input.length() > 1)`.

Comment: Check out the Character class.  Lots of `is*` tests for various characters and types.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is `abc` then check for the input length if it's greater than 1 then its invalid. eg:

```
String ip = input.next();
ch = ip.charAt(0) ;  
if(ip.length()>1){
    System.out.print("invalid"); 
}else if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') { 
    // rest of your code
```

To check special characters you can use `regex-pattern`. using a regex pattern you can check whether the character is a special symbol or not.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]");
String ip = input.next();
if(regex.matcher(ip).find())){ 
    // it returns true if the input contains any other character rather than letter,digits and spaces.
    //your code 
}
```

Also alternatively, you predefined your symbols beforehand in a `String` variable and check whether the given input is a special character or not. eg:-

```
String specialChars = "()\"{}_[]|\\?/<>,./*!@#$%^&*"; // if I missed any special character add it please 
if(specialChars.contains(ip)){
    //your logic
}
```